# Mongoose - pushing object into nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to push a student object inside 'students' object of team object. The below are the details.

**I got the solution for the from Niel. Have noted it at the end.**
Team.js

```
var TeamSchema = new Schema({
    // Team Name.
    name: String,
    lead: String,
    students :type: [{
      block : Number,
      status : String,
      student : {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Student'
    }]
});
```

Student.js

```
var StudentSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   rollNo : Number,
   class : Number
});
```

**Expected output**

```
team
{
    "__v": 1,
    "_id": "5252875356f64d6d28000001",
    "students": [
        {
            "__v": 1,
            "_id": "5252875a56f64d6d28000002",
             block : 1,
             status : invited,
            student: {
                "name": Sumeeth
                "rollNo" : 2
                "class" : 5
            }
        },
        {
            "__v": 1,
            "_id": "5252875a56f64d6d28000003",
            block : 1,
            status : invited,
            student: {
                "name": Sabari
                "rollNo" : 3
                "class" : 4
            }
        }
    ],
    "lead": "Ratha",   
}
```

**Current Output**

```
team

{
    "__v": 1,
    "_id": "5252875356f64d6d28000001",
    "students": [
        {
            "__v": 1,
            "_id": "5252875a56f64d6d28000002",
             block : 1,
             status : invited
        },
        {
            "__v": 1,
            "_id": "5252875a56f64d6d28000003",
            block : 1,
            status : invited
        }
    ],
    "lead": "Ratha",   
}
```

This is JS I use to get the document using Mongoose in TeamAPI.js

```
exports.students= {

    /*
     * ### Create Player
     */
 create: function(req, res) {
 var _team = req.team;
        var student = req.body;
        var _student = new Student(student);
            Student.create(student);
            _team.update({
                $push: {
                    students: {
                        student: new Student(student),
                        block : ‘1’,
                        status: 'invited'
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

**Solution**

```
var _student = new Student(student);                        
            _student.save();
            _team.update({
                $push: {
                    students: {
                        student: _student,
                        invite: _invite,
                        status: 'invited'
                    }
                }
            }
```

Some one please help me where I am wrong. How should I make use of push, so that , I can get the student object inside team.

Comment: Your Schema is referenced which means you only store the `_id` and store the student in it's own model. Do you actually want embedded where everything is in the same model for team?

Comment: Its also enough for me if get like team{ players { player: <objectId> }} so that I can add .populate({path:player}) to get the entire object at query. The problem is I dont get 'player' inside 'players'

Comment: Then your push is working as expected, but you need to "save" the "Student" to it's model as well in order to populate.

Comment: Student.create(student); - this line saves the student successfully to student model. But  $push: {
                    students: {
                        student: new Student(student) is not working. There is no 'student' inside 'students' of team.

Comment: It does not "embed" because you have not asked it to. You are asking for a reference to the "ObjectId" only. This means you use populate to retrieve the detail from the other model. Also what you need to do is "keep" the created object so that the `_id` value is the same as you "saved" it.

Comment: "what you need to do is "keep" the created object so that the _id value is the same as you "saved" it." This the reason for the error. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56404/discussion-between-sabari-and-neil-lunn).